# Is there a "how to" for the 10K moderator tools?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

So I just reached 10,000 rep. Yay! :)  Apparently I now have access to moderator tools.

But how do I use these moderator tools? I click on `Tools` at the top, and when I click on a tab, I see helpful things like:

> Now that you've achieved 10000 reputation, you've earned the right to see (and undelete) deleted posts, and vote to delete questions that have been closed for 2 days.
>
> You also have access to these moderation tools:
>
> - posts flagged as offensive or spam
> - recently deleted posts
> - recently closed questions
> - recently imported questions
> - see all recent edits in chronological order
> - new posts by new users
> - questions with newly created tags
> - new answers to old questions
> - recent questions with most view velocity
> - recent questions with most edit velocity
> - recent questions with most vote velocity
> - recent wiki changes
> - recent wikis created

So I click on, say, the first link (flagged posts), so I can see the tools available to me, and this is what I see:

> **Where should I start?**
>
> Start at the top. This list is ordered by a combination of number (and type) of issues, the reputation of the user who posted, and the flag history and reputation of the flagging user.

Okay, I'll "start" at the top...

...start doing what, though?

I don't see any "tools" here, only a list of the flagged posts. Is there something I'm missing? Or are the moderator "tools" just statistical information we can't really do anything about?

Comment: Yes, I was a bit underwhelmed at first, too.

Comment: @Gabe: Yeah... it makes me reconsider what I thought Jeff meant by "there is little difference between users with high reputation and ♦ moderators"... there seems to be **a world** of difference between them. :\

Comment: Thank you for posting the list - it satisfied my curiosity which drove me earning points. Now I don't need to do this anymore :).

Comment: @Mehrad: When Jeff first wrote that it was more true. Since then the Diamond Powers (tm) have gained new and spiffier tools. I started by making use of the pending close and delete lists, and then learned the rest of the goodies slowly.

Comment: @dmckee: So you mean the Diamond Powers (tm) didn't always have the ability to, for example, delete posts and comments? Is that really a recent change?

Comment: @Mehrdad: They had plenary deletion powers on posts and comments, but they could turn comments into answers or vice versa, couldn't migrate to arbitrary sites, had fewer informational tools on problem users and suspect posts and so on. They always had more power, but if was the difference between being part of a all powerful committee and being an autocrat in and of themselves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [Matt Haughey's Video Offering Advice to Community Moderators](http://www.psfk.com/2011/03/metafilters-matt-haughey-offers-advice-to-community-moderators.html).  This information will help you understand what each one of those 10k tools can do for you.  Metafilter has tools that are very similar to the ones that we have at our disposal.

The video is pretty long, but if you want to make a difference as a 10k user and are unsure of where to start, this resource will help you picture how to best use these tools.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll try to look at it when I have time; thanks. So apparently there's no real "tools" other than voting to delete old questions, right? :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: depends on your definition of "tool", I guess. I consider the various 10k reports as tools, that I can use to more effectively retag, flag, review suggested edits, etc.

Comment: @Michael: Well by "tool" I meant "the capability to perform an action that improve the site", and it seems like the only extra ability we gained for moderation is deleting old closed questions. Like @Gabe mentioned, it's a bit underwhelming... there's still miles and miles of differences between diamond moderators and 10k "moderators", contrary to what Jeff said. (TBH, I was originally surprised that anyone would actually give any random user "moderation" privileges on his site, and now I see it's not actually happening.)

Comment: *To access this content it looks like you’ll need to upgrade your account. The content you are trying to access is reserved for PSFK Members.* You'll need to register now and you will have to accept newsletters.

Comment: Oh, forget it, even the free 'Email Newsletter account' is insufficient to see the video, you need to dish out $95/month minimum. This is a strange site. You actually register with wallkit.net. *And* the only thing they seem to do is mail you 'news'letters, *and* there is no 'Delete your account'. OTOH a helpful chat support person offered to delete my account.

Comment: Is that [this video](https://vimeo.com/21043675)?