# How does a reputation of 10k or more display in the main bar at the top of the page?

Tags: discussion, reputation, information-display

Once your reputation has gone to 10k or more (I think), it changes display from 8943 to 42.8k. Is this how it will be displayed at the top of the screen (next to the nav)? Or is the full value shown ie 72153?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full value is shown, like so:

[image]

And it's a good thing it does, because otherwise how will I know when people are lavishing praise upon me??

Comment: Ohh whats that tools tab?

Comment: @added Those are the [moderator tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86554/156620).

Comment: @addedlovely that's the moderators tools, the orange box is the outstanding flag count and the other box is the pending suggested edits box